# How to recover [unknown] disk from LVM2 on Proxmox

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, lvm, proxmox

On my server, i have 5 disks. The disks are configured as follows:

**Raid 1 (Disk 1 + Disk 2) [320gb each]** - Proxmox installed

**Raid 1 (Disk 3 + Disk 4) [1tb each] + HDD (Disk 5) [1tb] = totalizing 1.82tb grouped** - Proxmox Storage LVM-thin

The disks where proxmox was installed are damaged! I replaced the disk and reinstalled the proxmox. I tried to add storage on the proxmox again, but:

```
# pvdisplay
Couldn't find device with uuid 58rBdr-2iGB-Reeq-P6BQ-qMme-WFhr-m64WTj.
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               [unknown]
VG Name               fileserver
PV Size               931.48 GiB / not usable 4.71 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238458
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          238458
PV UUID               58rBdr-2iGB-Reeq-P6BQ-qMme-WFhr-m64WTj

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb1
VG Name               fileserver
PV Size               931.48 GiB / not usable 4.71 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238458
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          238458
PV UUID               3MBpT2-zal5-6pC3-3qaw-avFv-62FD-0EGFvS

--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda3
VG Name               pve
PV Size               279.11 GiB / not usable 4.28 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              71452
Free PE               4094
Allocated PE          67358
PV UUID               7Mex80-ORk5-h7VL-B5jr-6bAU-xzIN-XfiIbw
```

and:

```
# lvscan
Couldn't find device with uuid 58rBdr-2iGB-Reeq-P6BQ-qMme-WFhr-m64WTj.
inactive          '/dev/fileserver/files' [1.82 TiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/fileserver/vm-100-disk-1' [100.00 GiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/fileserver/vm-101-disk-1' [600.00 GiB] inherit
inactive          '/dev/fileserver/vm-103-disk-1' [1.46 TiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/swap' [8.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/root' [69.75 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/pve/data' [181.66 GiB] inherit
```

Any tips on what can be done?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you did, any attempted answer to this question would be essentially a wild guess.

Comment: Even being a guess, anything could already help!

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site, not a Question and Guess site.